# Clipping a sampler2D in shader

Tags: webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to clip or cut the left side out of a loaded sampler2D texture in a shader before I return the texture2D.

Currently I am making the texture edits before passing to the shader but this is happening multiple times a frames which is killing performance. Can the texture edit be done in the shader instead?

I'm passing the texture first:

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);
```

And then using it as a uniform in the shader.. 
Would I clip it in the fragment shader or the vertex shader?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, can't you just sample the part of the texture you want to use by adjusting the texture coordinates used for sampling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by `clip the texture`. You don't clip textures. You read data out of textures and decide what you want to do with that data. Example

```
// don't draw anything if the texture coords reference the right half
// of the texture.
if (someTexCoords.x > 0.5) {
   discard;
}
gl_FragCoord = texture2D(someSampler, someTexCoords);
```

Or

```
// Draw red if texture coords access the right half of the texture
vec4 texColor = texture2D(someSampler, someTexCoords);
gl_FragCoord = mix(texColor, vec4(1,0,0,1), step(0.5, someTexCoords.x));
```

etc..

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This achieved exactly what I needed by discarding based on the coordinates. I've been banging my head against the keyboard for days trying to figure that out!